# How to find touchpad's device name?

Tags: touchpad, input-devices

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438725/disabling-middle-click-on-bottom-of-a-clickpad-touchpad) to disable middle click in the bottom of my touch pad.

Running `xinput list` gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

However `xinput get-button-map "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"` does not seem to give me the button map.

**EDIT**:
I tried this again and now I get the expected result when running `xinput get-button-map "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`. I must have had some mistake previously.

Comment: Did you wrap the name in quotes? what was the exact error message? You can try the device ID number instead (the number after the `id=` in the `xinput list` output)

Comment: I've tried to wrap the name with single quotes and double quotes, neither work. The id number did not work either.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact commands that you are typing, and the complete error messages

Comment: While following your advice I got the problem solved, edited the question.